# Despite the fact that 'fibo' package installed, it is not defined

Tags: python, python-module, python-packaging

```
def fib(n):    # write Fibonacci series up to n
a, b = 0, 1
while a < n:
    print(a, end=' ')
    a, b = b, a+b
print()

def fib2(n):   # return Fibonacci series up to n
result = []
a, b = 0, 1
while a < n:
    result.append(a)
    a, b = b, a+b
return result
import fibo
```

line 16, in 
import fibo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fibo'

C:\Users\rehim>pip install fibo

Requirement already satisfied: fibo in c:\users\rehim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (1.0.0)

Comment: Have you installed other packages with pip before? Is this the first time you've experienced and issue with installation?

Comment: do you have 2 python installed by any chance?

Comment: @HarshaBiyani, yes I have 2 python installed

Comment: @ColinHicks, i have had experience with python, and it is the first time i have experienced issue with installation

Comment: @HarshaBiyani, I forgort to say that I have deleted the previously installed python. This is the result:                                                                       
C:\Users\rehim>python
Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

Comment: which version have you uninstalled?

Comment: @HarshaBiyani,     Python 3.8.3 version for 32 bit, because system type in my PC is  x64-based

Comment: try with `pip3 install fibo`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217350/discussion-between-rehim-hesimov-and-harsha-biyani).